# Reading struct pointer from an Android Renderscript

Tags: android, pointers, struct, renderscript

I am having difficulties reading struct pointer data from an Android Renderscript.

Below is an extract from my Renderscript:

```
typedef struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Point_t;

Point_t *points;

void loadPoint() {
    points[0].x = 180;
}
```

And here is an extract from my Java code:

```
...

mOutputPoints = new ScriptField_Point(renderScript, 60);
mInterestPoints = new ScriptC_interestPoints(renderScript);
mInterestPoints.bind_points(mOutputPoints);

mInterestPoints.invoke_loadPoint();
ScriptField_Point.Item item = mOutputPoints.get(0);
// item is always null
```

The Android developer docs say that "In the Renderscript runtime layer, you can read and write to memory with pointers as normal and the changes are propagated back to the Android framework layer" however The above code doesn't read the pointer data set in the Renderscript.

Can anyone tell me how to correctly read struct pointer data set in a Renderscript?